# How to solve $-\frac{5}{8} = \sin\left(72 - \frac{4}{5}\phi\right) - \sin(\phi) - \frac{5}{4}\sin(90-\phi)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have worked out an equation required for a problem I have in work to calculate $n$-sides of a polygon within a circle with limited information supplied.

I have been able to simplify it down to this point but I am now stuck.

How do I solve for $\phi$?

I know answer is around $16.25$ (trial & error) but how to I simplify this equation to compute myself (as I need to convert to code)

$-\dfrac{5}{8} = \sin\left(72 - \dfrac{4}{5}\phi\right) - \sin\phi - \dfrac{5}{4}\sin(90-\phi)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! See [Basic Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @LightYagami Thank you, was wondering how this was done

Comment: Is it sin(-5/8) or -5/8 on LHS? Because in the title you have written sin(), which makes no sense.

Comment: You can apply the identities for $\sin(a-b)$ and use $\sin  \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi\right)=\cos \phi$.

Comment: @LightYagami it is -5/8 on LHS. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Could you please show me how to use these identities to solve the equation?

Comment: You can read about trigonometric identities on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities), I will try to write an answer for you.

Comment: Thankyou very much! You are awesome, much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple exact answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same, it would really get messy. Do you want an exact closed form?

Comment: Any answer / simplification would be great. If the equation gives multiple answers I'm sure I can use basic logic to select the required answer

Comment: @LeeScott Wolframalpha gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+-5%2F8%3Dsin%282pi%2F5-4x%2F5%29-sin%28x%29-5%2F4cos%28x%29), so I  hope you understand that the answer is not "simple".

Comment: Solution is $\phi =16.3777^{\circ}$. Exact solution is VERY difficult because of the $\frac{4}{5}\phi$. An approximation is better than nothing. There are other solutions, tho, like $\phi =121.52^{\circ}$.